# Eclipse is showing status as Launching: Starting Virtual Machine takes very long time

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using

OS:- Windows 7 sp1
Eclipse:- eclipse-jee-2021-03-R-win32-x86_64
JDK:- v16
Hardware:- Intel Core i5 (1st gen) M480 2.6 Ghz
RAM:- 6 GB

I tried to change `eclipse.ini` file as below:-

```
-vm C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-16\\bin
--plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.2.v20210201-0955/jre/bin 
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Xms800m
-Xmx4096m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

After doing this also even while running any simple program. My eclipse hangs continuously.

[image]

Not sure is that problem with my machine or RAM. Any suggestions would be really welcome.

Comment: Your `eclipse.ini` is invalid (`-vm` and path to the VM must be 2 separate lines directly before `-vmargs`; `--` does not uncomment a line; missing lines before `-vm`; see https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) and changing it not the right way to change the VM used to launch your application. Instead, configure the VM you want in the preference in _Java > Installed JREs_, so you can use it in your projects (_Project > Properties_) and in your launch configurations (tab _JRE_).

Answer (score 0):

6 GB is pretty small amount for a dev machine. I'm not saying it's impossible or even rare to have, but at the very least, you'll be giving your OS swap space a very good workout to try to keep up with running your OS, Eclipse (using up to 4 GB based on your above settings) and every other app you may have open.

For starters, try setting your Eclipse contribution to memory usage lower, i.e. instead of

```
-Xms800m
-Xmx4096m
```

Try using this instead:

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
```

This will try to give your Eclipse a fixed 1 GB to work with which is likely less than your Eclipse is trying to use now with the 4-GB upper limit you already have. You could try even lower settings, but there will be a minimum amount where if you start getting even lower than Eclipse itself will start behaving badly. Feel free to experiment, though.